# jQuery: hide/show element on radio box changing checked & hover

Tags: jquery, hover, mouse, forms

I've tried for a few hours to get a solution for the following problem. I did it with a rather complex

- A list with a radio-box selection, with a description of the selected radiobox below it;
- On mouse hover over each item, the description in the same position appears (all other descriptions disappear);
- When the mouse does not hover on an item, the description matching the checked radiobox will appear (all other descriptions disappear);

I fully admit that my jQuery knowledge is at a minimum level, mostly because I never need to use it myself. Spending a few hours on Google and some puzzling got me everything but a working solution for the entire problem. I had a working JS script for it a while ago with just too much code, looking at where I am now it looks like Jquery can give me a much shorter and cleaner code.

Right now I got the following HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .options .active {font-weight: bold;}
   .descriptions span {display: none;}
   .descriptions span.active {display: block;}​
</style>

<div class="options">
   <label><input name="permForumcon" type="radio" value="10" /> option1</label>
   <label><input name="permForumcon" type="radio" value="50" />option2</label>
   <label><input name="permForumcon" type="radio" value="70" /> option3</label>
</div>

<div class="descriptions">
   <span>description1</span>
   <span>description2</span>
   <span>description3</span>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {
options = $('.options > label');
descriptions = $('.descriptions > span');
options .each(function(idx) {$(this).data('slide', descriptions.eq(idx));}).hover(
    function() {
        options .removeClass('active');
        descriptions.removeClass('active');             
        $(this).addClass('active');  
        $(this).data('slide').addClass('active');
     }, function() {
        switches.removeClass('active');
        slides.removeClass('active');
         $('input[name=permForumcon]:checked + label').addClass('active') //this is where is already doesnt seem to work
        }
 );});
```

on Jsfiddlle: http://jsfiddle.net/mqcP9/8/

The problem that remains is, it(the added active class on both the label in options and the span in descriptions) doesn't change back to the selected radiobox. I tried several things which are visible commented when looking at the jsfiddle  sandbox. Anyone who could help me on the last part?

Comment: your jsfiddle link is broken, can you correct the link?

Comment: What is the problem in this fiddle?

Comment: @rajasaur I don't see why it doesn't work, since it works here and gdoron doesn't seem to have any problem either. The jsfiddle only contains come commented not-working lines, I doubt it's really needed to see how much I fail, I just wanted to make it easier for those who go further on the code.

Comment: @gdoron The 'active' class, and thus the description-selection, doesn't get added to the label for the radio-box when going out the hover state. (sorry if I'm unclear, it's almost 4am here)

Comment: @BrittaGeertsen - The solution to your problem is very very simple if the problem is understood clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this as your "off-hover" function:

```
function() {
    options.removeClass('active');
    descriptions.removeClass('active');
    $('label:has(input:checked)').addClass('active');
    $('label:has(input:checked)').data('slide').addClass('active');
}
```

Your selector for the checked label was off, that was really the root of it.

Comment: it seems to work in jsfiddle, time bring the knowledge into practice, Thanks a lot

Comment: Sure thing! Definitely take some time to review the options for selectors, though...In general, whatever's rightmost in the string is what's selected, when what you wanted was the parent of the checked input. That's why they have a number of psuedo-class selectors, to move up in the parent hierarchy.